# I/O card couples analogue ground to 0V - how can I work around this?

Tags: analog, ground-loop

I'm building a system that has to measure analogue voltages accurately. This system is being tested using PC-based test equipment that has an expansion card in it generating both digital and analogue signals. The digital signals also route to the system under test.

My problem is that the system under test has a measurement offset error of around 50mV.

The cause of this appears to be that the PC expansion card couples the analogue ground reference AGND to 0V. This is a surprise, because AGND and 0V are clearly distinguished on the labels of the card's output pins, and I expected them to be isolated. The 0V and AGND are intentionally joined in the system under test very close to the ADC.

It looks as though part of the return current that should be flowing in the 0V line is instead flowing down the AGND connection to the expansion card and causing the AGND near to the ADC to be at a slightly higher potential than at the expansion card source. If I temporarily replace the analogue inputs to the system under test using the outputs of a fully isolated power supply, the measurement offset goes away.

I am at a loss as to how to resolve this. I can't modify the system under test. Is it perhaps possible to put a unity-gain isolation amplifier between the expansion card and the system under test? Or replace the expansion card with one that isolates AGND and 0V from each other?

Comment: GND is the reference point to which usually all voltages are referenced to, as such any net labeled 0V should be expected to have zero potential to that point. If you have a measurement system you always have one point that you do your voltages against (unless you have a part that is floating and that doesn't affect anything else). Often you tie everything at one specific GND point in the whole system.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty crap card. Can you get one with differential inputs, or set the inputs you have to differential mode? Some high end (price wise)  have a pseudo-differential mode (low resistance to ground- just high enough to prevent large ground currents from flowing) that can cause interesting problems.

Comment: PlasmaHH: Thanks for your observation. You are right, but the problem here is that the ground nets have a small but finite resistance, so the current flowing to ground is causing a small offset voltage to develop. I need a way to reduce the ground current back to the analogue source and thus reduce this offset. There's a good discussion of this issue in Tim Williams / Peter Wilson's book "The Circuit Designer's Companion".

Comment: Spehro Pefhany: I can't disagree with your assessment of the card, but note that it's an analogue output (D to A), not an input (A to D). Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isolation amplifier would work, but an instrumentation amplifier would probably be cheaper and do the job. The INA217 for example is a pretty good general purpose one, and does unity gain. They also usually have better bandwidth.

Comment: That is an excellent idea. I have run a SPICE simulation using the LT1167 amplifier, and that indicates that your suggestion will solve the problem. I'll try it for real when the amplifiers arrive and let you know. Thanks very much.

Comment: The addition of an instrumentation amplifier worked very nicely. The offset error is now reduced to a millivolt or thereabouts. Great answer.